ERROR : *java: the unnamed module reads package com.digitalpersona.onetouch.ui.swing from both dpotapi and dpfpenrollment*
Getting this error when I run a project am building using digital person sdk in java. I continuously encounter the following:
ERROR : java: the unnamed module reads package com.digitalpersona.onetouch.ui.swing from both dpotapi and dpfpenrollment

The will not run and i have been stuck

can you please provide some context and the error stack.
But based on what you write, it look like that, two dependencies have the same package, so you need to exclude it in one of them.
